# SQL - Select TOP 1 from child table with WHERE condition, 2 possible values and 1 is preferred

Tags: sql, sql-server, cross-apply

I have 2 tables, parent and a child with 1-N relation.

- `Person`: Id (INT), Name (VARCHAR)
- `PersonToCompany`: Id (INT), PersonId (INT), Email (Varchar)

I want to JOIN both tables, but select just 1 record from the `PersonToCompany` table. I know I can do this using e.g. CROSS APPLY, but I also have some conditions.

I want to select only specific `PersonToCompany` records, like this:

```
WHERE (Email LIKE '%@abc.com%' OR Email LIKE '%xyz.com%')
```

Now the tricky part - some people can have 2 `PersonToCompany` records with both *@abc.com* and *@xyz.com* email domains. In this case, I want to be sure that the record with *@abc.com* will be selected. How can I do that?

This is my original subquery that selects *@abc.com* OR *@xyz.com* with no preference:

```
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 
    PersonToCompany.Email AS Email
    FROM PersonToCompany 
    WHERE PersonToCompany.PersonId = Person.Id
    AND (PersonToCompany.Email LIKE '%@abc.com%') OR (PersonToCompany.Email LIKE '%@xyz.com%')
) PersonToCompany
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TOP 1` without `ORDER BY` is "give me a row, I don't care which one". So the simple fix is to add an `ORDER BY`:

```
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 
    PersonToCompany.Email AS Email
    FROM PersonToCompany 
    WHERE PersonToCompany.PersonId = Person.Id
    AND (PersonToCompany.Email LIKE '%@abc.com%' OR
         PersonToCompany.Email LIKE '%@xyz.com%')
    ORDER BY CASE WHEN PersonToCompany.Email LIKE '%@abc.com%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
) PersonToCompany
```

(I've also shifted some parentheses around to get the logic correct, I believe - you were bracketing individual predicates, which doesn't really do anything. I've bracketed the `OR` so that the `PersonId` match is required no matter which email address is found, which sounds more correct to me)

Comment: Smooth! I didn't see I could use CASE inside of ORDER BY in this way.  And you were right about the parenthesis, I messed them up when I was desperately experimenting with the query. Thank you so much!